# wordpress include file

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have put some php code in a sidebar-01.php

i like in my template file to get that code

How do u do that ? (i don't what to change the code of WP for updating purpose)

i have try include('sidebar-01.php); - it don't work

i like to have a function like : get_header(); for my file, something like : get_file('sidebar-01')

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the 'Theme Editor', look for sidebar.php. Edit it and place this code there:

```
include('sidebar-01.php');
```

Also, remember to place your `sidebar-01.php` in *same folder* as the other theme .php files (basically your theme folder).

Answer (score 1):

Try the `get_sidebar()` function defined in `wp-includes/general-template.php`

Answer (score 0):

If your sidebar file name is `sidebar-home.php` then call it like this

```
get_sidebar('home');
```